# Sorting with linked lists using the qsort algorithm

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm still learning how linked lists works and I'm kinda struggling with the sorting using qsort algorithm and the nodes .
This is what I did so far .

So I'm having a crash somewhere in the code and I don't know if this qsort algorithm works this way with the linked lists or not.

Code Updated

```
void swapString(char **str1, char **str2)
{
    char *temp = *str2; 
    *str2 = *str1;
    *str1 = temp;
}

TCD *partition(TCD *Start, TCD *End, int (*cmp)(const void *, const void*))
{
    TCD *partitionIdx = Start;
    TCD *i ;
   
    for (i = Start; i != End; i=i->Next)
    { 
        if (cmp(i->Titel, End->Titel) < 0)
        {
            swapString(&i->Titel, &partitionIdx->Titel);
     
            partitionIdx->Prev = partitionIdx;
            partitionIdx = partitionIdx->Next;
        }
    }

    swapString(&partitionIdx->Titel, &End->Titel);
    
    return partitionIdx; 
}

void Quicksort(TCD *Start, TCD *End, int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    if (Start !=NULL && End != Start && End!= Start->Next)
    {
        TCD *partitionIdx = partition(Start, End, cmp);
       
        Quicksort(Start, partitionIdx->Prev, cmp);
        Quicksort(partitionIdx->Next, End, cmp);
    }
}
```

By the way , this is the definition of TCD

```
typedef struct F
{
 char *Titel;
 struct F *Next;
 struct F *Prev;
}TCD;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217342/discussion-on-question-by-gaston-sorting-with-linked-lists-using-the-qsort-algor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1. The line `partitionIdx->Prev = partitionIdx;` does not make sense. It causes a node to point to itself. This cannot be correct. The purpose of a linked list is for a node to point to the next node and the previous node, but never to itself.
2. Your function `partition` is crashing because its parameter `Start` will sometimes point to a place in the linked list beyond the `End` parameter. This is because you call the function `Quicksort` without ensuring that its `Start` parameter does not point to a place beyond the `End` parameter.
3. The `if` condition `if ( Start != NULL && End != Start && End != Start->Next )` does not make sense. The sub-expression `End != Start->Next` tests if the size of the partition is 2. If that is the case, the partition is not processed. However, a partition of size 2 must be sorted, so it must be processed. Only if the size is 1 should it not be processed.

I have changed the code of your algorithm by fixing the issues mentioned above, and it seems to work now. Also, I have added some functions to test the algorithm. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct F
{
    char *Titel;
    struct F *Next;
    struct F *Prev;
} TCD;

void swapString( char **str1, char **str2 )
{
    char *temp = *str2;
    *str2 = *str1;
    *str1 = temp;
}

TCD *partition( TCD *Start, TCD *End, int( *cmp )(const void *, const void*) )
{
    TCD *partitionIdx = Start;
    TCD *i;

    for ( i = Start; i != End; i = i->Next )
    {
        if ( cmp( i->Titel, End->Titel ) < 0 )
        {
            swapString( &i->Titel, &partitionIdx->Titel );

            //NOTE: I disabled the following line from the original code, as it was doing nonsense. It was causing a node to point to itself.
            //partitionIdx->Prev = partitionIdx;

            partitionIdx = partitionIdx->Next;
        }
    }

    swapString( &partitionIdx->Titel, &End->Titel );

    return partitionIdx;
}

void Quicksort( TCD *Start, TCD *End, int( *cmp )(const void *, const void *) )
{
    //NOTE: In the following if condition, I disabled part of the original code, because a partition of two elements must be sorted
    if ( Start != NULL && End != Start /*&& End != Start->Next*/ )
    {
        TCD *partitionIdx = partition( Start, End, cmp );

        if ( Start != partitionIdx )
            Quicksort( Start, partitionIdx->Prev, cmp );
        if ( partitionIdx != End )
            Quicksort( partitionIdx->Next, End, cmp );
    }
}

// NOTE:
// The following functions are not part of the algorithm, but are only
// used to test the algorithm.

void AddToList( TCD **head, TCD **tail, char *str )
{
    TCD *p;

    //allocate new node and fill it with the data
    p = malloc( sizeof(*p) );
    assert( p != NULL );
    p->Titel = str;
    p->Next = NULL;
    p->Prev = *tail;

    //attach new node to list by updating head or next pointer
    if ( *head == NULL )
        *head = p;
    else
        (*tail)->Next = p;

    //update tail pointer too
    *tail = p;

}

void PrintList( FILE *stream, TCD *head )
{
    TCD *p;

    for ( p = head; p != NULL; p = p->Next )
    {
        fprintf( stream, "%s\n", p->Titel );
    }

    fprintf( stream, "\n" );
}

void FreeList( TCD *head )
{
    TCD *p = head;

    while ( p != NULL )
    {
        TCD *tmp = p;

        p = p->Next;

        free( tmp );
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    TCD *head = NULL, *tail = NULL;

    //create linked list with a bit of unsorted test data
    AddToList( &head, &tail, "string8" );
    AddToList( &head, &tail, "string4" );
    AddToList( &head, &tail, "string2" );
    AddToList( &head, &tail, "string7" );
    AddToList( &head, &tail, "string3" );
    AddToList( &head, &tail, "string5" );
    AddToList( &head, &tail, "string1" );
    AddToList( &head, &tail, "string6" );

    //print list before sorting
    fprintf( stderr, "List before sort:\n" );
    PrintList( stderr, head );

    //do the actual sorting
    Quicksort( head, tail, strcmp );

    //print list after sorting
    fprintf( stderr, "List after sort:\n" );
    PrintList( stderr, head );

    //free the linked list
    FreeList( head );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Andreas. The reason of some nonsense code that I wrote is that I wanted to translate my code with the qsort algorithm and with the normal arrays to a qsort with linked lists without doing a lot of thinking .

Comment: @Gaston: If you want to perform sorting with linked lists, you may want to try [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) instead, as that algorithm is more efficient for linked lists.